# How to get Season Only achievements "Lore Books" in Diablo III?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I know it's a bit late to ask this, but there is a category of *Season only* achievements in Diablo III for *Lore Books*.

There are no achievements listed in there so I'm wondering: how one would go about getting them?

Thanks?

Comment: Either they are the same as the non seasonal and aren't listed, or they just don't exist and can't be unlocked anyways.

Comment: I'm asking because I just completed the seasonal achievement _Taking notes_ so I assumed I'd get another achievement for the _Lore Books_ but no. I'll try and see if I get something after all the achievements for Act I.

Comment: As an update, completing all the achievements related to lore books in Act I (Campain) did not add an achievement to _Lore Books_ in _Season Only_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now it is unavailable.
The patch that recently came out has features and achievements that do not unlock until next season.